# When do dependent random variables passed through nonlinear functions have the same conditional PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, transformation, density-function

Say there are 3 random variables $x$ and $y$ where $y$ depends on $x$ through $$y=f(x).$$
Furthermore, say there is another random variable $z$ that depends on $y$ through $$z=g(y).$$
Then, when is the relation
$$ p(x\mid y) = p(x\mid z),$$
valid ($p$ is the pdf of a random variable)? Is it only when $g$ and $f$ are both invertible?

Answer (score 1):

For example, when $f$ is not invertible, but $g(y)=y$, you certainly have your relation, so invertibility on both is not required.

Comment: Thank you @gt6989b for your answer. Nice example. So is it a necessary condition that $g$ be invertible? I'm trying to find a reference that lists the necessary and sufficient conditions for the relation to hold.